# How to find the Laplace Transform of $t^2sin(t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

Using the rule: $$\mathcal{L}(t^nf(t))=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}F(s)$$

where in this case
$$f(t)=\sin(t),\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\mathcal{L}(\sin(t))=F(s)=\frac1{s^2+1},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,n=2.$$
Find the 2nd derivative of F(s):

$$\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\Big(\frac1{s^2+1}\Big)=\frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}$$

The transform:

$$\mathcal{L}(t^2sin(t))=(-1)^2\frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}$$
$$= \frac{6s^2-2}{(s^2+1)^3}$$

Comment: @ stevesy $L[f\cdot g]\neq L[f] \cdot L[g]$

Comment: Which means I cannot multiply one transform by the other, but I can multiply one function by the other and then transform the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$L[f\cdot g]\neq L[f] \cdot L[g]$$
You should use :

$$L[t^{n}f(t)] =  (-1)^{n}F^{(n)}(s)$$

Where $F(s) = L[f]$ and $F^{(n)} (s)$ is the nth derivative of $F$.

In your case $n=2$

Comment: I found a formula similar to the one you mentioned GaussTheBauss which I can somewhat understand.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

$L\{tf(t)\} = \int_0^{\infty} tf(t) e^{-st} dt$

if we integrate both sides with respect to $s.$

$\int L\{tf(t)\} ds = -\int_0^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt = -L\{f(t)\}$

And then we can differentiate both sides (with respect to $s$).

$L\{tf(t)\} = -\frac {d}{ds} L\{f(t)\}$

$L\{t^2\sin t\}=\frac{d^2}{ds^2} \frac {1}{s^2+1}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\mathcal{L}(f(t))=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} \ dt.$$

Differentiate under the integral sign twice with respect to $s$ , and we get

$$\frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}(f(t))}{\partial s^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty} t^2 f(t) e^{-st} \ dt=\mathcal{L}(t^2 f(t)).$$

What happens when $f(t)=\sin(t)$ ?